# How can I translate a texture using the mapping node?

Tags: texturing, procedural

In the past, I've used a Mapping node to translate textures, but in this example it doesn't seem to work. I imagine it has something to do with that Scale input of that second Noise node(?).

How should I proceed recreating this kind of texture, but with a way that it could be translated using the Mapping node?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

so I toyed around a bit, I'd say this doesn't look quite as good, but it will scroll, I can explain a bit more if you want but I think it's easier to understand if you look yourself at it. I exposed some options, size controls the scale of the edge mask noise, and mapping is where you connect the mapping node to scroll, but if you want finer control go inside the group and tweak the ramps.
Sorry for jumping to conclusions earlier, I should have taken more time to test.

[image]

old post (this is wrong):

This is because this first noise texture node is only controlling the scale of your second noise, which is the one that is actually controlling the look of the texture the most.

The mapping node should be connected to the noise node right before the ramp node.

Comment: I tried that too but when I try to adjust those Location sliders in the Mapping node, it breaks the texture like this: http://i.imgur.com/J6ScAFg.png

Comment: Connect the mapping to both noise textures so that they both move together.

Comment: yeah I was careless I didn't test enough, now I'm knee deep in about 20 mapping nodes, I think I found a work around but I think it doesnt look as good as this method. will post if I get it working.

Comment: I got something working, test it out, it scrolls OK, tough the transition is not as close to your reference.